# Как использовать вторичные ключи в клиенте для golang

Tags: golang, aerospike

Есть вторичный ключ site_id, нужно получить все записи по нему, но в документации aerospike ничего подобного не нашел. Хотя в самом aql используется просто bin = value;

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming Google Translate properly translated your question :) )

If site_id is a number, you should be able to use the [`range query`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) API. For strings, I don't think there is a direct way at this point... There are potential other ways to get all the keys with a specific bin, for example [predexp filters](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) on top of a scan, or maybe even defining a set for all those keys and using a scan. May not be as efficient, though.

---

(Перевод сообщества.)

Если site_id — число, то можно воспользоваться API `range_query`. Для строк, не думаю, что сейчас есть такая возможность... Есть пути получить ключи с определённым bin, например фильтры predexp в scan'е или может быть даже определить множество этих ключей и использовать scan. Правда, это не особо эффективно.

Answer (score 1):

Мы нашли такую штуку как [NewEqualFilter](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/go/usage/query/query.html) для драйвера golang.  Работает с вторичными индексами как и нужно было.

Comment: Correct, the `NewEqualFilter` API is the correct Go API for finding `where bin = value`. Seems our Google Translator provided a different translation `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Comment: By the way, assuming Translation goes better in the future, for API questions it would be helpful to also know which client language (c, java, go, ...) that you are using.